# Download multiple files with a single action

Tags: http, web-applications, download

I am not sure if this is possible using standard web technologies.

I want the user to be able to download multiple files in a single action. That is click check boxes next to the files, and then get all the files that were checked.

Is it possible - if so what basic strategy do you recommend. I know I can use comets technology to create server side events that trigger an HttpResponse but I am hoping there is a simpler way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54626214/9715289 you can run this twice and this works fine.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

HTTP does not support more than one file download at once.

There are two solutions:

- Open x amount of windows to initiate the file downloads (this would be done with JavaScript)
- ***preferred solution*** create a script to zip the files

Comment: Why is a zip file the **preferred** solution? It creates an extra step for the user (unzipping).

Comment: This page contains javascript which creates ZIP file. Look at the page it has a great example. https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: A third way is to encapsulate the files into a SVG file. If the files are displayed in the browser, the SVG seems to be the best way.

Comment: HTTP itself supports multipart message format. But browsers don't portably parse multipart responses from the server side, but technically there's nothing difficult with doing this.

Comment: This can be an excelent solution with javascript https://github.com/sindresorhus/multi-download

Comment: @juananruiz the above solution will only work for the first file if the user requests to specify a location as to where the file(s) will be downloaded. it looked promising though - thx for sharing

Answer (score 100):

```js
var links = [
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.exe',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.dmg',
  'https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar'
];

function downloadAll(urls) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');

  link.setAttribute('download', null);
  link.style.display = 'none';

  document.body.appendChild(link);

  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    link.setAttribute('href', urls[i]);
    link.click();
  }

  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="downloadAll(window.links)">Test me!</button>
```

Comment: It works in Chromium, but doesn't work in Safari. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I am working with many file types, including pictures, and this worked best for me. However, `link.setAttribute('download', null);` renamed all my files to null.

Comment: It does not work in IE 11, it only downloads the .jar (last item in the list) it was the perfect solution :(

Comment: @AngeloMoreira Yep, at least it works in Edge. If you try downloading multiple files in IE on MS sites, [for example](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17062), they spawn multiple pop-up windows, so i think best solution for IE is still from [Dmitry Nogin above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9425731/2438165).

Comment: @tehlivi - I found the same thing.  Add the `link.setAttribute('download',filename)` inside the loop.  This allows you to name the files anything you wish.  Also, I believe it needs to be the filename only not including the URL.  I ended up sending two arrays:  one with the full URL and one with just the filename.

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution as well which seems great but also can't get it to work in firefox, is there a workaround?

Comment: @zaheer It's not working in Chrome because Chrome blocks spammed downloads.

Comment: Someone rejected my edit. But I'll leave it here: add the following [code]link.setAttribute('download', urls[i].split('/').pop().trim());[/code] inside the for loop.

Comment: In Mac Safari (v12.1), this downloaded only the Minecraft.jar file.  (It did not download the .exe and .dmg files.)

Comment: It is working fine on Chrome, but on Firefox only first file inside an array is getting downloaded and after that it comes out of loop.

Comment: It does not work properly in Chrome v75, Windows 10: The only file that is downloaded is `Minecraft.jar`.

Comment: This is not the right approach for most of the modern browsers, only the last file will be downloaded.

Comment: not working, only the last file is downloaded

Comment: this solution is eight years ago, maybe not for modern web

Comment: The principle is OK: create a[href], add to document, click it programmatically, except each URL needs its own a[href] or chug the thing on the event loop such the DOM part gets "rendered" and a click is processed before the next one has its turn.

Answer (score 60):

You can create a temporary set of hidden iframes, initiate download by GET or POST inside of them, wait for downloads to start and remove iframes:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <button id="download">Download</button> 

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

     $('#download').click(function() {
       download('http://nogin.info/cv.doc','http://nogin.info/cv.doc');
     });

     var download = function() {
       for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
         var iframe = $('<iframe style="visibility: collapse;"></iframe>');
         $('body').append(iframe);
         var content = iframe[0].contentDocument;
         var form = '<form action="' + arguments[i] + '" method="GET"></form>';
         content.write(form);
         $('form', content).submit();
         setTimeout((function(iframe) {
           return function() { 
             iframe.remove(); 
           }
         })(iframe), 2000);
       }
     }      

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, without jQuery:

```
 function download(...urls) {
    urls.forEach(url => {
      let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.style.visibility = 'collapse';
      document.body.append(iframe);

      iframe.contentDocument.write(
        `<form action="${url.replace(/\"/g, '"')}" method="GET"></form>`
      );
      iframe.contentDocument.forms[0].submit();

      setTimeout(() => iframe.remove(), 2000);
    });
  }
```

Comment: awesome, but for some reasons the files are not getting downloaded. To me the reason seems that the page reloads after script is executed, seems to be the reason for files not getting downloaded. Any clue on what wrong I am doing?

Comment: I've got multiple issues with this solution. In IE since my parent window has changed the document.domain, I have an access denied. There's various post about fixing this, but all feel hacky. In Chrome, user gets prompt a warning message telling the web site tries to donwload multiple files (but a least it works). In Firefox, I get different dowload box but when I click Save, I don't get the save file dialog...

Comment: This didn't work for me, because the file dialog "blocks" the other save dialogs to appear. What I did was something slightly hacky - the mousemove action registers only *after* the file dialog disappears, so I used that - but it's not tested. I will add it as another answer.

Comment: Does this work in IE10? I get: Object doesn't support property or method 'write'

Comment: why the returned function (closure?) on `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Won't this still require the user to confirm each file download individually?  If so, I wouldn't really count that as a "single action".

Comment: I was able to use this for .docx but images do not work.

Comment: I was trying to multiple download some PDF's but the download was not starting, after a bit of debugging I realise what has happened, the PDF was rendering inside the iframe and not downloading.

Comment: Why is `${url.replace(/\"/g, '"')}` needed? It doesn't seem to do anything. Wouldn't `${url}` be sufficient?

Answer (score 53):

This solution works across browsers, and does not trigger warnings. Rather than creating an `iframe`, here we creates a link for each file. This prevents warning messages from popping up.

To handle the looping part, we use `setTimeout`, which is necessary for it to work in IE.

**Update 2021**: I am aware that the "run code snippet" no longer works, but that's due to cross site cookie issues. The code works fine if deployed on your own site.

```js
/**
 * Download a list of files.
 * @author speedplane
 */
function download_files(files) {
  function download_next(i) {
    if (i >= files.length) {
      return;
    }
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = files[i].download;
    a.target = '_parent';
    // Use a.download if available, it prevents plugins from opening.
    if ('download' in a) {
      a.download = files[i].filename;
    }
    // Add a to the doc for click to work.
    (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
    if (a.click) {
      a.click(); // The click method is supported by most browsers.
    } else {
      $(a).click(); // Backup using jquery
    }
    // Delete the temporary link.
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
    // Download the next file with a small timeout. The timeout is necessary
    // for IE, which will otherwise only download the first file.
    setTimeout(function() {
      download_next(i + 1);
    }, 500);
  }
  // Initiate the first download.
  download_next(0);
}
```

```html
<script>
  // Here's a live example that downloads three test text files:
  function do_dl() {
    download_files([
      { download: "https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt", filename: "robots.txt" },
      { download: "https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt", filename: "standards.txt" },
      { download: "http://qiime.org/_static/Examples/File_Formats/Example_Mapping_File.txt", filename: "example.txt" },
    ]);
  };
</script>
<button onclick="do_dl();">Test downloading 3 text files.</button>
```

Comment: This is the only one in here that worked for me, since I have to support IE. Thank you.

Comment: This answer is golden. Only one that works in all browsers without a warning message. Specially IE. 
Brilliant stuff

Comment: Not working in Chrome OSX, it asks me to allow multiple download but even if I do, only the first file is downloaded and I heard an amount  of "beep" corresponding to the number of files to download left

Comment: Button does nothing `Google Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Comment: Button not working in stack overflow Run code snippet. Browser Crome @speedplane

Comment: @1934286 It doesn't **do nothing**, take a look at your browser's console, the script's just blocked for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, the code still works, but Stack Overflow changed their security policy and it no longer runs properly within the code snippet runner. If you are putting this on your own server, you can set whatever security policy you want.

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore. It only downloads the FIRST file without warnings.

Comment: This solution did not worked with react js

Comment: I was able to use this code inside a react component without issue. Thank you for the help!

Comment: what about images :(

Answer (score 6):

The following script done this job gracefully.

```
var urls = [
'https://images.pexels.com/photos/432360/pexels-photo-432360.jpeg',
'https://images.pexels.com/photos/39899/rose-red-tea-rose-regatta-39899.jpeg'
];

function downloadAll(urls) {


  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    forceDownload(urls[i], urls[i].substring(urls[i].lastIndexOf('/')+1,urls[i].length))
  }
}
function forceDownload(url, fileName){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
        var tag = document.createElement('a');
        tag.href = imageUrl;
        tag.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
        tag.click();
        document.body.removeChild(tag);
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Drawback: no "download interrupting-continuing" feature like regular downloads have (with browser negociating automatically with server through range requests)

Comment: This works, but when I run it, it seems to be downloading the files twice. Any thoughts?

Comment: @cbartell, may be you have appended urls twice in the urls array, test the above given sample if this also downloading files twice.

Comment: This actually download file as blob. So user wont be able to see the progress.

Comment: With `urls` already defined globally it's not necessary to pass as argument. `downloadAll() {` seems to suffice. Put it behind a button and it works nicely :-)

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way would be to serve the multiple files bundled up into a ZIP file.

I suppose you could initiate multiple file downloads using a bunch of iframes or popups, but from a usability standpoint, a ZIP file is still better. Who wants to click through ten "Save As" dialogs that the browser will bring up?

Comment: I realize your answer is from way back in 2010, but a lot of users are browsing with smartphones nowadays, some of which can't open zips by default (a buddy tells me his Samsung S4 Active can't open zips).

Answer (score 4):

I agree that a zip file is a neater solution... But if you have to push multiple file, here's the solution I came up with. It works in IE 9 and up (possibly lower version too - I haven't tested it), Firefox, Safari and Chrome. Chrome will display a message to user to obtain his agreement to download multiple files the first time your site use it.

```
function deleteIframe (iframe) {
    iframe.remove(); 
}
function createIFrame (fileURL) {
    var iframe = $('<iframe style="display:none"></iframe>');
    iframe[0].src= fileURL;
    $('body').append(iframe);
    timeout(deleteIframe, 60000, iframe);             
 }
 // This function allows to pass parameters to the function in a timeout that are 
 // frozen and that works in IE9
 function timeout(func, time) {
      var args = [];
      if (arguments.length >2) {
           args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
      }
      return setTimeout(function(){ return func.apply(null, args); }, time);
 }
 // IE will process only the first one if we put no delay
 var wait = (isIE ? 1000 : 0);
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
      timeout(createIFrame, wait*i, files[i]);
 }
```

The only side effect of this technique, is that user will see a delay between submit and the download dialog showing. To minimize this effect, I suggest you use the technique describe [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx) and on this question [Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download) that consist of setting a cookie with your file to know it has started download. You will have to check for this cookie on client side and to send it on server side. Don't forget to set the proper path for your cookie or you might not see it. You will also have to adapt the solution for multiple file download.

Answer (score 4):

A jQuery version of the iframe answers:

```
function download(files) {
    $.each(files, function(key, value) {
        $('<iframe></iframe>')
            .hide()
            .attr('src', value)
            .appendTo($('body'))
            .load(function() {
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(that).remove();
                }, 100);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Each is looking for an array. This will work: `download(['http://nogin.info/cv.doc','http://nogin.info/cv.doc']);` However, this does not work for downloading image files.

Answer (score 4):

Angular solution:

> HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app='app'>
        <head>
            <title>
            </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body ng-cloack>        
            <div class="container" ng-controller='FirstCtrl'>           
              <table class="table table-bordered table-downloads">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>File name</th>
                    <th>Downloads</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat = 'tableData in tableDatas'>
                    <td>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="{{tableData.name}}" id="{{tableData.name}}" value="{{tableData.name}}" ng-model= 'tableData.checked' ng-change="selected()">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{tableData.fileName}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a target="_self" id="download-{{tableData.name}}" ng-href="{{tableData.filePath}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right downloadable" download>download</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>              
                </tbody>
              </table>
                <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" ng-click='downloadAll()'>download selected</a>

                <p>{{selectedone}}</p>
            </div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);            
app.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter){

$scope.tableDatas = [
    {name: 'value1', fileName:'file1', filePath: 'data/file1.txt', selected: true},
    {name: 'value2', fileName:'file2', filePath: 'data/file2.txt', selected: true},
    {name: 'value3', fileName:'file3', filePath: 'data/file3.txt', selected: false},
    {name: 'value4', fileName:'file4', filePath: 'data/file4.txt', selected: true},
    {name: 'value5', fileName:'file5', filePath: 'data/file5.txt', selected: true},
    {name: 'value6', fileName:'file6', filePath: 'data/file6.txt', selected: false},
  ];  
$scope.application = [];   

$scope.selected = function() {
    $scope.application = $filter('filter')($scope.tableDatas, {
      checked: true
    });
}

$scope.downloadAll = function(){
    $scope.selectedone = [];     
    angular.forEach($scope.application,function(val){
       $scope.selectedone.push(val.name);
       $scope.id = val.name;        
       angular.element('#'+val.name).closest('tr').find('.downloadable')[0].click();
    });
}         


}]);
```

working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/XynXRS7c742JPfCA3IpE?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, I created a JS library to stream multiple files directly into a zip on the client-side. The main unique feature is that it has no size limits from memory (everything is streamed) nor zip format (it uses zip64 if the contents are more than 4GB).

Since it doesn't do compression, it is also very performant.

Find "downzip" it on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downzip) or [github](https://github.com/robbederks/downzip)!

Answer (score 3):

This works in all browsers (IE11, firefox, Edge, Chrome and Chrome Mobile) My documents are in multiple select elements. The browsers seem to have issues when you try to do it too fast... So I used a timeout.

```
//user clicks a download button to download all selected documents
$('#downloadDocumentsButton').click(function () {
    var interval = 1000;
    //select elements have class name of "document"
    $('.document').each(function (index, element) {
        var doc = $(element).val();
        if (doc) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = doc;
            }, interval * (index + 1));
        }
    });
});
```

This is a solution that uses promises:

```
 function downloadDocs(docs) {
        docs[0].then(function (result) {
            if (result.web) {
                window.open(result.doc);
            }
            else {
                window.location = result.doc;
            }
            if (docs.length > 1) {
                setTimeout(function () { return downloadDocs(docs.slice(1)); }, 2000);
            }
        });
    }

 $('#downloadDocumentsButton').click(function () {
        var files = [];
        $('.document').each(function (index, element) {
            var doc = $(element).val();
            var ext = doc.split('.')[doc.split('.').length - 1];

            if (doc && $.inArray(ext, docTypes) > -1) {
                files.unshift(Promise.resolve({ doc: doc, web: false }));
            }
            else if (doc && ($.inArray(ext, webTypes) > -1 || ext.includes('?'))) {
                files.push(Promise.resolve({ doc: doc, web: true }));
            }
        });

        downloadDocs(files);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve on @Dmitry Nogin's answer: this worked in my case.

However, it's not tested, since I am not sure how the file dialogue works on various OS/browser combinations. (Thus community wiki.)

```xml
<script>
$('#download').click(function () {
    download(['http://www.arcelormittal.com/ostrava/doc/cv.doc', 
              'http://www.arcelormittal.com/ostrava/doc/cv.doc']);
});

var download = function (ar) {
    var prevfun=function(){};
    ar.forEach(function(address) {  
        var pp=prevfun;
        var fun=function() {
                var iframe = $('<iframe style="visibility: collapse;"></iframe>');
                $('body').append(iframe);
                var content = iframe[0].contentDocument;
                var form = '<form action="' + address + '" method="POST"></form>';
                content.write(form);
                $(form).submit();
                setTimeout(function() {    
                    $(document).one('mousemove', function() { //<--slightly hacky!
                        iframe.remove();
                        pp();
                    });
                },2000);
        }
        prevfun=fun; 
      });
      prevfun();   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a solution to do this, but unzipping the files in javascript was not as clean as I liked. I decided to encapsulate the files into a single SVG file.

If you have the files stored on the server (I don't), you can simply set the href in the SVG.

In my case, I'll convert the files to base64 and embed them in the SVG.

Edit: The SVG worked very well. If you are only going to download the files, ZIP might be better. If you are going to display the files, then SVG seems superior.

Answer (score 0):

When using Ajax components it is possible to start multiple downloads. Therefore you have to use https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow

Add an instance of AJAXDownload to your Page or whatever. Create an AjaxButton and override onSubmit. Create an AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior and start downloading.

```
        button = new AjaxButton("button2") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
        {
            MultiSitePage.this.info(this);
            target.add(form);

            form.add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.milliseconds(1)) {

                @Override
                protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    download.initiate(target);
                }

            });     
        }
```

Happy downloading!

Comment: javascrpt?!?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Below code 100% working.

**Step 1**: Paste below code in **index.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ang">

<head>
    <title>Angular Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <button ng-click="files()">Download All</button>
    </div>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Step 2**: Paste below code in **index.js** file

```
"use strict";

var x = angular.module('ang', []);

    x.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
        var arr = [
            {file:"http://localhost/angularProject/w3logo.jpg", fileName: "imageone"},
            {file:"http://localhost/angularProject/cv.doc", fileName: "imagetwo"},
            {file:"http://localhost/angularProject/91.png", fileName: "imagethree"}
        ];

        $scope.files = function() {
            angular.forEach(arr, function(val, key) {
                $http.get(val.file)
                .then(function onSuccess(response) {
                    console.log('res', response);
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('download', val.fileName);
                    link.setAttribute('href', val.file);
                    link.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.appendChild(link);
                    link.click(); 
                    document.body.removeChild(link);
                })
                .catch(function onError(error) {
                    console.log('error', error);
                })
            })
        };
    });
```

**NOTE** : Make sure that all three files which are going to download will be placed in same folder along with *angularProject/index.html* or *angularProject/index.js* files.

Comment: do u rilly knead ayng[the last  airbender]ular for thuis/???

Answer (score 0):

Getting list of url with ajax call and then use [jquery plugin](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)  to download multiple files parallel.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            blockUI("body");
        },
        complete: function () { unblockUI("body"); },
        success: function (data) {
           //here data --> contains list of urls with comma seperated
            var listUrls= data.DownloadFilePaths.split(',');
            listUrls.forEach(function (url) {
                $.fileDownload(url);
            });
            return false; 
        },
        error: function (result) {
            $('#mdlNoDataExist').modal('show');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest solution (at least in ubuntu/linux):

- make a text file with the urls of the files to download (i.e. file.txt)
- put the 'file.txt' in the directory where you want to download the files
- open the terminal in the download directory from the previous lin
- download the files with the command 'wget -i file.txt'

Works like a charm.

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting downvoted. This works perfectly, thank you much.

Comment: It is not very user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I do that. I open multiple ZIP but also other kind of data (I export projet in PDF and at same time many ZIPs with document).

I just copy past part of my code.
The call from a button in a list:

```
$url_pdf = "pdf.php?id=7";
$url_zip1 = "zip.php?id=8";
$url_zip2 = "zip.php?id=9";
$btn_pdf = "<a href=\"javascript:;\" onClick=\"return open_multiple('','".$url_pdf.",".$url_zip1.",".$url_zip2."');\">\n";
$btn_pdf .= "<img src=\"../../../images/icones/pdf.png\" alt=\"Ver\">\n";
$btn_pdf .= "</a>\n"
```

So a basic call to a JS routine (Vanilla rules!). 
here is the JS routine:

```
 function open_multiple(base,url_publication)
 {
     // URL of pages to open are coma separated
     tab_url = url_publication.split(",");
     var nb = tab_url.length;
     // Loop against URL    
     for (var x = 0; x < nb; x++)
     {
        window.open(tab_url[x]);
      }

     // Base is the dest of the caller page as
     // sometimes I need it to refresh
     if (base != "")
      {
        window.location.href  = base;
      }
   }
```

The trick is to NOT give the direct link of the ZIP file but to send it to the browser. Like this:

```
  $type_mime = "application/zip, application/x-compressed-zip";
 $the_mime = "Content-type: ".$type_mime;
 $tdoc_size = filesize ($the_zip_path);
 $the_length = "Content-Length: " . $tdoc_size;
 $tdoc_nom = "Pesquisa.zip";
 $the_content_disposition = "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$tdoc_nom."\"";

  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");   // Date in the past
  header($the_mime);
  header($the_length);
  header($the_content_disposition);

  // Clear the cache or some "sh..." will be added
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($the_zip_path);
  exit();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
           <p class="style1">



<a onclick="downloadAll(window.links)">Balance Sheet Year 2014-2015</a>

</p>

<script>
 var links = [
  'pdfs/IMG.pdf',
  'pdfs/IMG_0001.pdf',
 'pdfs/IMG_0002.pdf',
 'pdfs/IMG_0003.pdf',
'pdfs/IMG_0004.pdf',
'pdfs/IMG_0005.pdf',
 'pdfs/IMG_0006.pdf'

];

function downloadAll(urls) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');

  link.setAttribute('download','Balance Sheet Year 2014-2015');
  link.style.display = 'none';

  document.body.appendChild(link);

  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    link.setAttribute('href', urls[i]);
    link.click();
  }

  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
</script>
```