# Display PDF on browser

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf

I want to display a PDF file on browser which is store on our server. Here is my code :-

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].folder_name.'/resources/uploads/pdf/pdf_label_'.$order['id'].'.pdf';

$filename = 'pdf_label_'.$order['id'].'.pdf';

$file = $path;
$filename = $filename;

  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile($file);
```

But it returns below output on browser :

```
%PDF-1.4 % 5 0 obj >stream
```

PDF File to show :

[image]

I am doing this on view of codeignter.

What I am doing wrong ? Please help me on this. thanks in advance

**EDIT :-**

Im doing something like below :

```
foreach($orders as $order){

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].folder_name.'/resources/uploads/pdf/pdf_label_'.$order['id'].'.pdf';

$filename = 'pdf_label_'.$order['id'].'.pdf';

$file = $path;
$filename = $filename;

  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  echo file_get_contents($file);

  }
```

So how can I show more than one file on browser ?

**Edit 2 :-**

So as per the answer below I have to use phpmerger to merge multiple PDF file and display into the browser. I gone through this website http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/ but unable to use into codeignter. Can anyone please help me to use this phpmerger inside my codeingter

Comment: This is a little side step, but you can generate those PDF's on the fly using fPDF. If you pull all the required fields from the db and generate the PDF, you can save yourself all the resources of storing them. It's very light weight and practical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `PDF Merger` library to achive your goals.
[Here is the link to original library (outdated).](http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/) 
[Prefer myokyawhtun fork which is maintained](https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger)

and a sample code will be as following

```
include 'PDFMerger.php';
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
$pdf->addPDF('path_to_pdf/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4')  //include file1 - pages 1,3,4
    ->addPDF('path_to_pdf/two.pdf', '1-2')      //include file2 -  pages 1 to 2
    ->addPDF('path_to_pdf/three.pdf', 'all')    //include file3 - all pages
    ->merge('browser', 'test.pdf');  // OUTPUT : make sure you choose browser mode here.
```

**Supported modes** - `browser`, `file`, `download` and `string`.

---

**Edit** : As i can see you have tagged CI you can put `PDFMerger.php` in `applications/libraries`.
and load it in `autoload.php` or in `controller`

and then can use it like `$this->pdfmerger->addPDF()` and `merge()` functions.

Comment: yes im using CI so as you said I have to include pdfmerger.php inside `applications/libraries` but there is another folder fpdf and fpdi should I upload it into the same location ? and  How can I load the merger in my controller ? Can you please help me how to use phpmerger in CI

Comment: copy `PDFMerger.php` in `application/libraries`. in `autoload.php` include `$autoload['libraries'] = array('pdfmerger',........` and then you can use it in CI as i have mentioned in answer :) @RakeshShetty

Comment: I tried and it is loaded but now it is throwing error - require_once(fpdf/fpdi.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: didn't copied `fpdf` and `fpdi` folders ??? after copying you'l get `Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated` if you are using PHP 5+ you need to remove `&` from those lines as its been deprecated in PHP 5+. @RakeshShetty

Comment: I have copied on system/libraires location

Comment: it should be `application/libraries` as i mentioned. `copy php file and both the folders`

Answer (score 21):

```
$filePath="file path here";
$filename="file name here";
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
header('Accept-Ranges:bytes');
@ readfile($filePath);
```

please try this code  i hope it will working as i try.

Comment: `filename="'.$filename.'"');` could be `filename="'.$filename);` (sorry all those quotes make my head fuzzy)

Comment: @James that would cause an unclosed double quoted string.  Please deal with your head fuzziness in a different way -- curly braces perhaps if you don't like dots.

Comment: @arshad please add some explanation to your code-only answer if you are able.

Answer (score 3):

Use exit after readfile:

```
$filepath = 'your-path/demo.pdf';
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header(sprintf("Content-disposition: inline;filename=%s", basename($filepath)));

@readfile($filepath);
exit;
```

ps. @ before readfile it's used to suppress errors, maybe remove it in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
@readfile($file);
```

Use

```
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Or ommit the `@`

Comment: thanks and i tried that file_get_contents($file);exit; it shows the pdf file but actually there is more than one pdf file and im using foreach to display pdf file. So when I remove exit; from file_get_contents($file); it shows %PDF-1.4 % 5 0 obj >stream

Comment: You cannot do multiple downloads at once (not without invoking the code multiple times from javascript via AJAX or something like that)

Comment: I think I told you how to achieve it in the previous comment

Comment: can I do something like this :- include_once($path); ?

Comment: @RakeshShetty No, you have to invoke the script multiple times... Via AJAX from the frontend of your application: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2339452/1857053

Comment: preferred solution create a script to zip the files - should I create a zip folder for my pdf files and then display the result as per your code ?

Answer (score 1):

my recommended library for embedding PDFs is PDFObject. Check it out here: http://pdfobject.com/

Answer (score 1):

This method works if you want to display a pdf in the browser page.

```
$file = 'filename.pdf';
echo "<embed src='$file' type='application/pdf' width='80%' height='600px' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Friends just use Anchor Tag that's it. 
Now-day's all newer browsers supports view of any files.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me on Chrome.

```
$path = $filename;
              header("Content-Length: " . filesize ( $path ) ); 
             // header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
              header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=".basename($path));
              header('Expires: 0');
              header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
              ob_clean();
              flush();
              //readfile($path);






          echo "<embed src='$path' type='application/pdf' width='80%' height='320px' />";
```