# How can I download all images in single click(Download all) by using PHP

Tags: php

If I click that Download All I need to download all that image to my local system

```
<div>
  <img src='image1.jpg'/>
  <img src='image2.jpg'/>
  <img src='image3.jpg'/>
  <button> Download All </button>
</div>
```

Give me some solution for this

Comment: Please explain what you have tried without success rather than asking for a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to download without zipped them, you can use a javascript function like this to download one to one:

```
function downloadWithName(uri, name) {
    function eventFire(el, etype){
        if (el.fireEvent) {
            (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
        } else {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
            evObj.initMouseEvent(etype, true, false, 
                 window, 0,
                 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 false, false, false, false,
                 0, null);
            el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        }
    }

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    eventFire(link, "click");
}
```

But, you need to make some changes in your code in order to allow to download all images with a single click. In your case, this code will run ;)

```
<div id="allImages">
  <img src='image1.jpg' />
  <img src='image2.jpg' />
  <img src='image3.jpg' />
  <button onclick="downloadAll()"> Download All </button>
</div>

<script>
function downloadAll(){
    var div = document.getElementById("allImages");
    console.log(div);
    var images = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    console.log(images)

    for(i=0; i<images.length ; i++){
        console.log(images[i]);
        downloadWithName(images[i].src,images[i].src);
    }
}

function downloadWithName(uri, name) {
    function eventFire(el, etype){
        if (el.fireEvent) {
            (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
        } else {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
            evObj.initMouseEvent(etype, true, false, 
                 window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 false, false, false, false,
                 0, null);
            el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        }
    }

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    eventFire(link, "click");
}
</script>
```

As you can imagine, you can add more `<img>` inside `<div id="allImages">` and user will download all together.

Comment: Its working in chrome,But its not working in mozilla

Comment: I have fixed for Firefox ;) In downloadWithName > eventFire you have to use initMouseEvent instead of initEvent. I have edited my answer, try it!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP does not support more than one file download at once.

There are two solutions:

- Open any amount of windows to initiate the file downloads (using JavaScript)
- Create a script to zip the file.

You could use try scripts from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action) for more options.

Comment: Ok will create zip file and try it out

Comment: If the answer was helpfull, please vote up or mark it as right,

Answer (score -3):

You can just left click on the website and select 'Save as..' (in Chrome) /  'save page as' (in Firefox). You will get all the images in that page in a folder. You do not have to use any scripts or any CLI.

Comment: the question is asking for a programmatic way to do this