# How we download multiple files (images, audio, video, txt ) on single click using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Download multiple files (images, audio, video, txt ) on single click using javascript and Jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download multiple files with a single action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP doesn't support downloading of multiple files. You can use a 3rd-party library like [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip//) to zip the files.