# Generate multiple PDF from Django view with Weasyprint

Tags: python, django, pdf, weasyprint

When user click download button I want to generate multiple pdf
Currently I can only generate one PDF

What I want is to generate two PDF from Django view when user click download button with weasyprint.

Below code only generate single PDF

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
    html_result = super(GenerateInvoicePDFView, self).get(*args, 
    **kwargs)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s.pdf"' % 
    obj.name
    weasyprint.HTML(string= html_result.getvalue()).write_pdf(response)
    return response
```

This response should generate two PDF, is it possible ? Please help Thanks

Comment: you can create archive or multi page pdf file, but no way for return multi file by response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download multiple files with a single action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return multiple files in the response. Only solution I see is zipping them, sending them to user by email, or creating two separate download buttons.

How about:

view:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'file-1' in self.request.GET:
        obj = self.get_object(file='file-1')
    else:  # I assume you always want to download some file
        obj = self.get_object(file='file-2')

    html_result = super(GenerateInvoicePDFView, self).get(*args, 
    **kwargs)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s.pdf"' % 
    obj.name
    weasyprint.HTML(string= html_result.getvalue()).write_pdf(response)
    return response
```

template:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="file-1" value="Download file 1" />
    <input type="submit" name="file-2" value="Download file 2" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ooh ! Can't I make them both download in single click

Comment: So what approach would suit you best? Merging those 2 PDFs into one, zipping them or sending them by email?

Comment: HTTP does not support more than one file download at once. Apart from solutions I've listed in previous comment, you can bind JavaScript to your button, so on single click it will open 2 separate tabs and trigger 2 download action.  Can't think of anything else at this moment.

But zipping them is best solution, as it will work on every browser.

Comment: @Pythonist How would you go about that option of merging the PDFs into one or zipping them?