# Download multiple jpg's with one click no zip

Tags: javascript, http, web-applications, download, jpeg

Looking for a way to download multiple images (.jpg) with just one click.

Try here :
http://adriano31.pythonanywhere.com/  for a **demo** use this code as input : **AMDBNBW**

I'm having hard time figuring this out. Ideally would not require any zipping but if there's no other clean, stable way of achieving this than zipping would work as well.

I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action#64) and trying a lot of this solutions but, lots of them are not supported by browsers these days.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your users will be pissed if you start many downloads from a single page. It's super annoying: Either you trash their download filter (if they auto-start downloads), or they'll be bugged with tons of download prompts.

Comment: @ThiefMaster what would you suggest than ?

Comment: To zip it - that's the only sane option there IMO, and considering that Windows has native ZIP file support it's the most user-friendly one as well.

Comment: @ThiefMaster ok. Would you mind showing me how to achieve this, please ?

Comment: You'd do that using server-side code - probably outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - ohhh...didn't thought it's going to be so difficult...hmmm...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180197/discussion-between-andie31-and-thiefmaster).