# File download from browser hangs first time, works on repeat

Tags: html, linux, file, nginx

I'm running nginx on my Linux box as a webserver. Nginx has been configured to permit file downloads. I've set up my webpage to permit download of files in a directory call 'logs' under /var/www/html.

Each file has a separate link on my webpage like this:

```
<a href="logs/file1234.dat" download="file1234.dat">Download</a>
<a href="logs/file2345.dat" download="file2345.dat">Download</a>
<a href="logs/file3456.dat" download="file3456.dat">Download</a>
```

When I click a link in Firefox, the e.g 'Opening file1234.dat' popup appears and 'Save File' becomes enabled. When I click 'Save File', it looks like nothing happens. If I inspect the download status bar, the browser claims

```
'Unknown time left - 0 bytes (0 bytes/sec)'
```

If I cancel the download and then restart it, the file downloads fine.

I also tried downloading multiple files in a list like here [Download multiple files with a single action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action) and the first file hangs on download, but the next files download fine.

What could be causing the first file download to hang?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes security software (anti-virus, firewall) is causing this sort of problems.
If you have some anti-virus software installed on your computer, try to disable it for some time to see if that makes a difference.