# Open multiple php files from one single click

Tags: html

I am downloading a PDF that gets generated from a php file through `GeneratePDF.php`. However I would like to open another php file that downloads another PDF. I would like to achieve this with one single click using ahref tag. How do I achieve this?
Set of phps I would like to open with one single click:

```
GeneratePDF.php
GeneratePDF2.php
```

```
<?php
session_start();
//

<td><a href="GeneratePDF.php" target="_blank"><button id="pdf" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pdf"" ></i>PDFs download</button></a></td>
//
?>
```

EDIT: Most importantly, how do I use onclick() function inside my above code. I am using php and the code given below does not really work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<td><a href="GeneratePDF.php" onclick= "window.open('GeneratePDF2.php');" target="_blank"><button id="pdf" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pdf"" ></i>PDFs download</button></a></td>
```

Comment: it is very likely a duplicate question and it does

Comment: Unfortunately the links I have used so far are to open pages. But my one line of code is for downloading multiple files. I dont know how to use that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action

Comment: I have updated few things in my question, could you please take a look at this?

Comment: Could you please post it as an answer in relation to my code? I am finding it bit complicated from my end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action here

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple, just remove the href tag, and use 2 onclick functions:

```
<td>
  <a onclick="window.open('GeneratePDF.php');window.open('GeneratePDF2.php');" target="_blank">
    <button id="pdf" name="generate_pdf" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fa fa-pdf">PDFs download</i>
    </button>
  </a>
</td>
```