# How to return multiple images using File Response?

Tags: laravel

I managed to send an image using File Response: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#file-responses

From the Controller:

```
public function get_image(Request $request) {
    $pathToFile = '../storage/uploads/460s6DLmCnvoom90S7wfk.jpg';
    return response()->file($pathToFile); }
```

But I need to return multiple images, but this doesn't work (In this example I use the same image just for the test):

```
public function get_images(Request $request)
{
    $images = [];
    $pathToFile = '../storage/uploads/460s6DLmCnvoom90S7wfk.jpg';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $images[] = response()->file($pathToFile);
    }
    return $images;
}
```

It only returns array of empty headers. I am using Fetch API (Or AJAX) to get the images

Comment: Well you can't do that, you will need to download each file with a different request, you can't have multiple responses for a single request, it's not related to laravel, but it's how http works, see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action . You can however make a zip file

Comment: I just wonder what is the best practice for my case, where I need to load 20 images every time (infinite scroll) - will I need to zip it, send it to frontend then unzip in frontend? Is it a good practice or it's too much of a performance hit?

Comment: the best practice is to use apache/nginx to load the images, and not laravel

Comment: I am using nginx, what should I do? Also, what do you mean by apache? Do you have a link to explanation where I can learn about it? Never done that before (Can I use both nginx as the server and apache to load the images?)

Comment: Well it depends on the webserver you use, if you use nginx then use it to handle file downloads, there is not much to do, put the files in a public folder somewhere that is served by nginx

Comment: Ok so the problem is (and why I used Laravel) is that these are user uploaded private images, so I did not want to put them in the publicly accessible folder - I put that below root. Maybe that's not how I should be doing it then?

Comment: You could try something like : https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/ i've not used it myself, but it seems to allow access to private files with nginx, by passing a header